# Can't Install Standard Plugins on a Local MAMP installation

Tags: plugins, permissions, local-installation

I've tried to install two standard plugsins (wp-touch was one).  I have a local installation under OS 10.6 and MAMP which otherwise seems to work fine.  I select the zip file but get the error message:
The uploaded file could not be moved to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06.

The directory didn't exist, so I created it.  I've also changed all the directories to read/write.  I still get the same problem.

I'm a unix virgin and new to macs, so please be gentle with me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the automated install feature. Go to the plug in folder and drop the plugin to there. Of course, unzip it first.

Answer (score -1):

Or you go through the WordPress admin interface:
Plugins > Add New > Search Plugins 
type wp_touch (for example) and then choose the plugin and click install.